# Calculations with a Markov chain

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, markov-chains, markov-process

> Let $(X_n)_{n \in N_0}$ be a Markov chain with the following graph:
>
> [image: chain]
>
> (a) Find its probability transition matrix.
>
> (b) Find all stationary (invariant) distributions of the Markov chain.
>
> (c) Let the initial distribution be $X_0 = (0.5, 0.5, 0)$. Calculate the distribution of $X_2$ and $P(X_0·X_2 = 1)$.

Here's my work:

(a) $P = \begin{bmatrix}0 & 0.5 & 0.5 \\0.5 & 0.5 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}.$

(b) Since $3$ is the only absorbing state, the stationary distribution has to be $(0, 0, 1).$

(c) The distribution of $X_2 = X_0 \cdot P^2 = (\dfrac{1}{4}, \dfrac{3}{6}, \dfrac{3}{8}).$

---

I'm not sure how to solve for $P(X_0 \cdot X_2 = 1)$. Is the question looking for $P(X_0 = 1, X_2 = 1)?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement of the question is a little muddled.   If the Markov chain is $\ \big(X_n\big)_{n\in N_0}\ $ with the transitions illustrated in the given graph and initial distribution $\ \pi_0=(0.5, 0.5,0)\ $, then $\ X_0\ $ must be the *state* at time $0$, a *random variable* which assumes the value $0$ with probability $0.5$ and the value $1$ with probability $0.5$.  It cannot be its own distribution, so using the same symbol "$X_0$" to represent that distribution is a confusing misuse of notation, which makes it a little puzzling as to what $\ P\big(X_0\cdot X_2=1\big)\ $ is supposed to mean.

However, your interpretation of it is the only one I can see that makes any sense.  Taking $\ X_0\ $ to be the *state* of the chain at time $0$ (rather than the distribution of that state), and $\ X_2\ $ to be its state at time $2$, the only way $\ X_0\cdot X_2\ $ can be $1$ is if $\ X_0\ $ and $\ X_2\ $ are both $1$.